# What to do with [nix] and [nixos] tags? (previous: A legitimate question ON HOLD because of wrong tags)

Tags: discussion, support, tags, scope

The question in topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271007/nix-cannot-create-a-profile

First, it is marked on hold because

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

I don't get this, should all Linux package manager's questions be posted in Super User?

The current situation is everyone asks on [nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nix) tag on Stack Overflow, not on Super User.

Should I stop answering questions on [nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nix) and [nixos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nixos) tags and point everyone to Super User?

Data point: Super User contains zero questions for [nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nix) tag. Another data point: using Nix package manager often requires some programming skills (not about topic question). Another data point: [nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nix) tag can refer to Nix language (not about topic question).

Second, question is tagged [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) and [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), which is wrong and these tags should be removed. But because of these tags, moderators found and quickly banned question. I edited the question, removed tags, but looks like somebody rejected my edit. So now I'm unable to answer the question and earn more rep ^.^

How can I figure out who have declined my edit?

---

[edit addendum]

I'd like to know what should I do with questions about Nix and Nixos. Those conceptually are related to systems administration, but also are tightly related to programming using Nix language. The question in topic was closed as inappropriate for Stack Overflow, but I see there exist tags [yum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yum), [pacman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pacman), [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) and so on, which should also be redirected to Super User.

Given a very little community around Nix/NixOS, explicit split between SO and SU will be harmful for such questions.

So, should I redirect [nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nix) and [nixos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nixos) questions to Super User in case they aren't at all related to programming?

Comment: In this particular case, what about the question's actual content seems on-topic for Stack Overflow? Not sure why you assume that the other tags have *anything* to do with the closure -- the fact that it's about a misbehaving piece of software, and in no way about a programming task, seems reason enough.

Comment: @PaulRoub "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming" An argument could be made that Nix is used for programming. In a similar way, questions about [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm) don't seem to be considered off-topic.

Comment: @PaulRoub yes, this question isn't about programming at all. I've already answered some similar questions about Nix recently, that's why I'm now suprised I shouldn't do that. I'll clarify the question a bit then

Comment: Please clarify why the linked question, *specifically*, is a "legitimate question" for Stack Overflow. "Sometimes nix questions are about programming" doesn't mean that *all* of them are.

Comment: @PaulRoub It directly involves a tool used primarily for programming. That seems to be evidence enough.

Comment: @MikeC It also has to be *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic The OP of that question needs to make it clear why their issue is a programming specific issue.

Comment: @PaulRoub I've clarified a question. Sorry didn't get it right the first time.

Comment: "An argument could be made that Nix is used for programming." You can make the same argument for your office chair.

Comment: I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294496/nix-removing-a-profile) about Nix yesterday, which isn't about programming but is (so far) well-received. So the tags [tag:ubuntu] and [tag:linux] were the reason for putting the previous question on hold. Also, there's nothing on Nix in SU (not even a tag), so it's unlikely to get any feedback there

Comment: Actually, I've discovered nix and nixos tags on https://unix.stackexchange.com, maybe that is a better place to ask those questions

Answer (score 4):

> Those conceptually are related to systems administration, but also are
>   tightly related to programming using Nix language.

If it's a programming problem or a problem that's only an issue in software development, then it's on topic here. The question itself needs to make it clear that it belongs in this category.

> Given a very little community around Nix/NixOS, explicit split between
>   SO and SU will be harmful for such questions.

They can't all be here or all on Super User. Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. Programming questions are explicitly [off topic at Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

> So, should I redirect [nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nix) and [nixos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nixos) questions to Super User in case
>   they aren't at all related to programming?

Yes. Such questions would be off topic here and subject to closure.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to create tags [[tag:nix]] and [[tag:nixos]] on Super User?

Comment: @danbst You'll need to ask someone with enough rep (1500) on that site.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow all the questions asked on Nix or NixOS on any SE site with this filter: https://stackexchange.com/filters/290349/nix-and-nixos (I personally have a filter for these and a couple more tags).

As you can see questions are evenly distributed between SO and Unix & Linux SE, plus (rarely) some on ServerFault.

As you can also see, the questions are already pretty well separated between those which are programming related ("how do I program in this language using Nix?" is a pretty standard question) which perfectly fit on SO and those which are more "Linux-related" which fit better on Unix & Linux SE.

So I feel the separation can continue to be enforced. Tagging a Nix question as off-topic on SO from time to time is not a problem thus.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Though that filter doesn't show questions [on hold], so topic question asker would get zero responses...

Comment: @danbst Interesting. I was not aware of that.

Comment: That being said, a question on hold can't receive any answer anyways.